# Google App Engine non-indexed list property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have this property in GAE:

```
memberNames = db.StringListProperty(indexed = False)
```

But for unindexed properties, they usually don't cost me any writes (just the basic write to put the file), but with this property, I'm getting writes for every string in the list. Am I not allowed to have non-indexed ListProperties? Is my only other choice to use a JSON array string or is there a way around this?

Comment: Why do you think you per per string item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StringListProperty creates several index rows (one row per value) and is stored only in the index, so you are correct that you need to implement your own serialization (e.g. JSON) of multi-value-properties rather than using StringListProperty to eliminate the index writes.

Comment: This doesn't explain why he's seeing extra writes when the property is set to unindexed.

Comment: I had that list properties were stored only as index values so didn't know that indexed=False could be applied to anything other than simple properties.